# How to read a file using showOpenFilePicker (NOT <input type="file">)

Tags: javascript, readfile

I want a cleaner UI than what

```
<input type="file" ...>
```

gives me.

I can use window.showOpenFilePicker() to get the user gesture security context and get a "fileSystemHandle" from that API but I can't figure out how to read that file using the FileReader object. (or any other way)

Here is my failing code:

```
/**
 * Used to import via a simple button.
 * The caller must call window.showOpenFilePicker() and give the
 * fileHandle to this API.
 * @param {*} fileHandle 
 * @param {*} fnImportToUI 
 */
fio.importFromFileButton = async function(fileHandle, fnImportToUI) {
  if (Array.isArray(fileHandle)) {
    fileHandle = fileHandle[0];
  }
  var blob;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('loadend', (event) => {
    blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(event.target.result)], {type: fileHandle.type })
    fnImportToUI(fileHandle, event.target.result)
  });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

The problem being that the fileSystemHandle is not a Blob (I get an error if I call

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileHandle);
or
reader.readAsText(fileHandle);
```

or using any of the ReadFile read APIs.)

From what I can tell, I can't convert the fileSystemHandle to a Blob until I have read the file to get the data - a chicken and egg issue.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work at all in either Firefox or Safari and doesn't work in **any** mobile browser (not even Chrome on Android), so most users aren't going see any UI at all...

Comment: That being said, if you can't resist the Siren's song, I believe you want to call `getFile` on the `FileSystemFileHandle` in the Promise returned by `showOpenFilePicker` and then `await` *that* Promise to get the `File` object (which N.B. is already a Blob). See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle/getFile) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) for more detail.

Comment: As @JaredSmith said with much reason, one should not use this cool FileSystem API without putting in place a fallback if ever the API is not available. Check this article where the author demonstrates a complete example of how you could use this. [link](https://web.dev/patterns/files/open-one-or-multiple-files)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where that code came from, but the correct way to use that API looks like this. Assuming you have a file `foo.txt` with the contents "Hello, world!" in it:

```
// Returns a Promise of a single File object
async function pickSingleFile() {
  const [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
  return await fileHandle.getFile();
}

// Takes a File object, returns a Promise of a string
async function readFile(file) {
  return await file.text();
}

pickSingleFile() // user picks foo.txt
  .then(readFile)
  .then(console.log) // prints "Hello, world!"
  .catch(console.error); // in case of oops
```

You can actually test this here, on this page, by creating a text file, pasting that code into your browser console (assuming you're on desktop Chrome or Edge) and navigating to the correct file in the file picker that opens.

Note as I said in the comments this feature has at the time of this writing [has abysmal support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker#browser_compatibility) and works only on desktop versions of Chromium-based browsers, no Safari, no FireFox, and no mobile (not even Chrome on Android), so think carefully before using.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was:

```
fio.importFromFileOpenPicker = async function(fileHandle, fnImportToUI) {
  let file = await fileHandle.getFile();
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('loadend', (event) => {
    fnImportToUI(file, event.target.result)
  });
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Just for clarity, fileHandle is what is directly returned from window.showOpenFilePicker();  You can't do that within this async function as it violates the user gesture security context.

Answer (score -1):

There are several mistakes in your snippet, I have fixed based on my assumptions. Code is pretty much self explanatory.

```js
/**
 * convert a File object into base64 dataurl or plain text, returns null if its aborted
 * @param {File} file
 * @returns {Promise<string|null>}
 * @param {'plain'|'base64'} mode
 */
 
const convertFileToDataURLOrString = (file, mode) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => resolve('' + reader.result))
    reader.addEventListener('abort', () => resolve(null))
    reader.addEventListener('error', () => reject(reader.error))
    if (mode === 'plain') reader.readAsText(file)
    else reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  })

fio.importFromFileButton = async function (fileHandle, fnImportToUI) {
  if (Array.isArray(fileHandle)) {
    fileHandle = fileHandle[0]
  }
  const datastr = convertFileToDataURLOrString(fileHandle, 'plain')
  // do something with datastr
}
```

Comment: I was confused about getFile() called directly on the returned fileSystemHandle vs fileSystemHandle[0].  Thanks.